# Alternative for PHPlivedocx?

Tags: php, templates, ms-word

Is there any other free alternatives to PHPliveDocx?  I would like to create a Word document based on templates and user inputted data.

The template will resides on the server and the client(online or c# windows application) will be used to collect user input.  Once data has been collected, server-side script(PHP) will be used to generate a Word document.  So far I have only found phplivedocx. However I'm not very comfortable at consuming web services from a server that I have no control over with (am I worrying too much?).

I have also thought about using client to do the work (c# windows application, Open Office XML).  But I'm not sure that's the right way of doing things.

Comment: For those reading and still looking, also looks https://github.com/djpate/docxgen might be an option, though didn't look too thoroughly.

Answer (score 3):

I'm searching for some tool/library like this too!

Right now I can point you to

[phpdocx](http://www.phpdocx.com/)

[tinybutstrong](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/)! check its opendocument and openxml plugin **opentbs**:

However I feel like there must be something different that should feet our needs better!

I will update this if necessary!

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

[OpenTBS](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php) is able to merge DOCX template in PHP the way you're describing.

It does Docx, Xlsx, Pptx, Odt, Ods, Odf, ... any OpenDocument and OpenXML documents.

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me, http://www.phpdocx.com/archives/1952 phpdocx library that converts a .docx to pdf :)