# Convert RTF File into HTML in Objective C

Tags: html, objective-c, xcode, ipad, rtf

How can I convert an RTF file into an HTMLformat ?? I have a text editor which saves the file in rtf format but I need to put the contents on my server. For that I need to convert the rtf file into that of an html.. I am unable to find any help with regards to Objective C . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any library in objective-c that does rtf to html conversion.

However if you are able to perform the conversion server side then that opens up a lot more possibilities, such as php and c# libraries, as well as gnu utilities.

For example (and you can google for many more):

**php:** Pa software's [RTF to HTML converter](http://www.pa-software.com/scripts/) (paid product), Martin Mevald's [rtf2htm](http://www.mevald.cz/oldprograms.php) (old GPL'ed software), Marcus Fischer's [RTF Parse class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1930-PHP-RTF-to-HTML-converter-with-latin-character-support.html) (GPL'ed code), Zend's [LiveDocX](http://www.phplivedocx.org/2009/08/13/convert-docx-doc-rtf-to-html-in-php/) or even alternatives to livedocx on SO [alternative-for-phplivedocx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452263/alternative-for-phplivedocx) .. etc

**C#:** On SO [convert-rtf-to-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439301/convert-rtf-to-html), [simple-convert-rtf-to-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265566/simple-convert-rtf-to-html), or from MS [Converting-between-RTF-and-HTML](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Converting-between-RTF-and-aaa02a6e)

**GNU:** GNU's [UnRTF](http://www.gnu.org/software/unrtf/) utility.

If you really want Objective-c then the source code of the php and GNU solutions could be translated - however that will not be a trivial task.  As such I still think your best bet would be to do it server side.